# While comparing two char arrays, they are identical but my code is saying they aren't

Tags: java

I am making a hang-man sort of a game. Currently, I imported a .txt dictionary. I am trying to compare a guess array to the word array. Both arrays are char data types. However, using blueJ I can tell that both arrays are identical but the if(workWord.equals(realWord)) is not executing.

```
while(togLoop) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a guess! ");
        char input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        for(int i = 0; i < wordGuess.length();i++) {
            if(realWord[i] == input){
                correct += 1;
                System.out.println("It is the " + (i + 1) + " letter");
                workWord[i] = input;

            }
        }
        if(workWord.equals(realWord)) {
            System.out.println("Congrats! You got it right!");
            togLoop = false;
        }
    }
```

~This is what blueJ is showing ~
[image: Image shows they are similar]

Answer (score 5):

Use `Arrays.equals` to compare arrays for equality.

Arrays inherit `equals` from `Object`, so two distinct array instances are never equal, even when their contents are the same.

```
char[] first = {'a'};
char[] second = {'a'};

System.out.println(first == second); // false
System.out.println(first.equals(second)); // false
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(first, second)); // true
```